# SFMC Query : Count Not Working

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sqlserver, sql

I am trying to count to number of subscribers have made a transaction. I am using the code below:

```
SELECT 

M.Id SubsriberKey
,COUNT (Transaction_ID__c) OVER (PARTITION BY M.Id) AS NumberOFTransactions 


FROM  MasterSubscriberDE M 

LEFT JOIN SalesDE S   

ON M.Id = S.Id

GROUP BY M.Id, S.Id, Transaction_ID__c
```

My query is returning zero for all the subscribers, even though there are transactions in the Sales table (i.e Transaction_ID_c is not empty).

[image]

I will appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Are you looking to count the number of subscriber with transactions or the number of transaction per subscriber?

Comment: Hi @DavidDevoy I am trying to count **number of transactions per customer**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you need to **partition** the data and you have too many fields specified in you **group by** statement.  Here is how I would revise the query.

```
SELECT 

M.Id SubsriberKey
,COUNT (S.Transaction_ID__c) AS NumberOFTransactions 

FROM  MasterSubscriberDE M 

LEFT JOIN SalesDE S   

ON M.Id = S.Id

GROUP BY M.Id
```

Comment: Hi David, I have ran your script and it seems to still not count the transactions per customer. I am editing the question to show the query I am using to validate the first one.

Comment: If the query is returning zeros in the NumbersOfTransactions column, then I would suspect the subscriberKeys in your MasterSubscribersDE are not in the SalesDE.  Check to make sure both DE(s) are storing the 18 char version of the subscriberkey.

Comment: This is the case. Thank you very much. Please update this in your answer so I can accept it.